# Repeat a php file every x hours forever

Tags: php

I have a `PHP` file i need the file to repeat every x hours after the `PHP` file is done,

Someone told me check out

```
watch -n x <your command>
```

but will this repeat after the `PHP` file is done?

Sorry I'm a newbie, Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
watch -n x your command
```

will repeat every x seconds. if your command last 10 minutes and you use
`watch -n 3600 your command` you'll only get 50 minutes between 2 commands. Each command will start exactly one hour after the previous one.

You may use sleep, and a loop, if you want to wait a given amount of time between 2 run. Sleep uses seconds. my example sleeps one hour, 3600 seconds.

```
while : ; do
  your command
  sleep 3600
done
```